# xCode load PhoneGap start page other than index.html

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova

I want to do a simple thing - load a start file named other than `index.html` based on a condition in Xcode 4.2 and PhoneGap 1.0.0. I found that the answer to this question is in the FAQ for iPhone PhoneGap, but I still can't find it. Is this really impossible to do? Because it is easily done in Android.

edit: I found that this line:

```
NSURL *appURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[PhoneGapDelegate pathForResource:@"index.html"]];
```

in `PhoneGapDelegate.m` must be modified with another file name, but how could I change it at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following code to your **AppDelegate.m**

```
+ (NSString*) startPage { 
    return @"YOU_PAGE.html"; 
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem another way, but this is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can open AppDelegate.m and search the line:

```
 self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

then replace "index.html" with the filename you need.

```
 self.viewController.startPage = @"another.html";
```

Comment: the file is in "Classes" folder.